# upper bound of 2-norm of a p dimensional Gaussian random variable?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, inequality, normal-distribution, normed-spaces

For $n$ iid observations $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ sampling from $p$ dimensional Gaussian distribution $N(\mu,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma>0$ and its eigenvalues are bounded away from zero and infinity, the average is $\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then as $n \to \infty$, what's the upper bound of $\|\hat{\mu}-\mu\|_2$ and $\|\hat{\mu}-\mu\|_\infty$? Does the results need other restrictions on $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the $L^2$ norm, note that $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\mu}] = \mu,$ so $||\hat{\mu}-\mu||_2^2$ is simply the trace of the variance:
$$tr\left[Var(\hat{\mu})\right] = tr(\Sigma/n) = tr(\Sigma)/n.$$
Hence, $||\hat{\mu}-\mu||_2 = \sqrt{tr(\Sigma)}/\sqrt{n}.$ This is an exact result for any $n.$

For the $L^\infty$ norm, we always get $||\hat{\mu}-\mu||_\infty=\infty,$ unless $\Sigma=0.$ Since if $\Sigma\neq 0$, then for any $n$ and any $K>0,$
$$\mathbb{P}(||\hat{\mu}-\mu||>K) > 0,$$
since $\hat{\mu}\sim N(\mu, \Sigma/n).$

If $\Sigma = 0,$ we have $\hat{\mu}=\mu$ a.s., so $||\hat{\mu}-\mu||_\infty=0.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I remember that $\|x\|_{\infty} \le \|x\|_2$ for a vector $x$. Is that true?

Comment: This is true in finite-dimensional vector spaces, but not in general.

Comment: I think $tr[Var(\hat{\mu})]=\mathbb{E}\|\hat{\mu}-\mu\|_{2}^{2}$ but not $\|\hat{\mu}-\mu\|_{2}^{2}$ itself. Maybe the Markov's inequality can be used to bound $\|\hat{\mu}-\mu\|_{2}^{2}$ based on your answer. :)

Comment: There are two norms that we denote by $||\cdot||_2,$ which can get a bit confusing. There is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^p,$ that is for a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^p,$ we have $||v||_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^p v^2_i.$ But for a random vector (or random variable) $X$ taking value in $\mathbb{R}^p$ we also have the $L^2$ norm $||X||_2^2 = \mathbb{E}|X|^2.$